# Associate Python / Django model objects with users

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am new to Django and Python, so I apologize if this is a very simple question.  I am building an application for my sons Elementary School.  The first leg of the project is to provide online access for parents to communicate with their child's teachers and vice versa.  I've created the models shown below that will allow the relationships in the database, but I need to be able to make the teachers and parents users as well with limited access based off their group roles.  Below is my models code.

The basic idea is that both teachers and parents have many relationships to the student model.  The teachers would be able to log into their portal and add the students that belong in their class.  The parents would be connected to the student, which would then provide a connection to the teacher.  Now as a users, the parent and teacher could send communications back and forth.

If that makes any sense, any help or feedback would be awesome. Oh, I know I need to import the auth.models, just don't know how or if I can connect to the teacher and parent classes.  Thank you.

```
from django.db import models


class Student(models.Model):
    student_first = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    student_last = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.student_first, self.student_last)


class Teacher(models.Model):
    teacher_first = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    teacher_last = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    teacher_email = models.EmailField()
    students = models.ManyToManyField(Student)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.teacher_first, self.teacher_last)


class Parent(models.Model):
    parent_first = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    parent_last = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    parent_email = models.EmailField()
    students = models.ManyToManyField(Student)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.parent_first, self.parent_last)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since both Teacher and Parent have the same fields I would go for a common model. Also, both are users so create a `OneToOneField` to `AUTH_USER_MODEL` (which provides first, last names and email).

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    '''
    Teacher or  Parent
    '''
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
    primary_key=True)

    students = models.ManyToManyField(Student)
```

Simply assing them to the appropriate parent/teacher group during registration so you can restrict access by [group](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#groups).

Comment: That looks so much cleaner than having two separate classes.  Sorry for the late reply.  I will implement this method and report back with outcome.  Thank you.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, but that got me where I needed to go. I got all wrapped up in overthinking the solution. Thank you.